# HTTP user agent block nginx restart fail

Tags: nginx, user-agent

I trying to paste the following on my

nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    access_log /var/www/logs/example_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/logs/example_error.log;
    root /var/www/html;

# case insensitive matching
    if ($http_user_agent ~* (netcrawl|npbot|malicious|wget)) {
        return 403;
    }

location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
}
```

}

```
service nginx reload && service nginx restart
```

I did the following at another server

```
wget "http://mymainserver.com/myfile.html"
```

It still able to 200 ok fetch the file.

Any idea what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Missing "**}**" in your config file

> nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting "}"

As a result, 
`nginx reload` fails and `service nginx restart` is not even not called.

OR

**server_name** in your config file mismatches *hostname* used in wget => nginx skips your location

Comment: oh thats not the issue, the nginx i paste is just part of the segment of the full config file, my reload & restart was fine.